# How to get list of matrices with rows of data frame as input?

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I have a data frame (2 columns, some rows) and a function that takes a vector of 2 numbers and builds a matrix out of it. My goal is to apply that function on each row of the data frame such that in the end I have a list of matrices. I tried the following

```
df <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6))
gen_mat <- function(x) matrix(c(x[1], x[1] + 1, x[2], x[2] +1), nrow = 2)
bad <- apply(df, 1, gen_mat)
```

Unfortunately, `bad` is not a list but a 4 by 3 matrix where each column contains the elements of one of the 3 generated matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this it?

```
bad2 <- lapply(as.data.frame(t(df)), gen_mat)
bad2
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why your solution works and `bad3 <- lapply(df, gen_mat)` does not?

Comment: Because `lapply` is meant for objects of class `list`. Since a `data.frame`is a list where all elements, the columns, are of the same size, `lapply` will process one *column* at a time. Now, you need to process rows. So, transpose the df. But this makes of it a `matrix`. Then you have to coerce the matrix to `data.frame`.